# tokenize application.conf in play java app

Tags: java, configuration, playframework, sbt

I want to tokenize a few keys in my application.conf file to use variables from another properties file. How can I do so? Here is an example.

> > my-play-project/conf/application.conf
> >     
> >     `db.default.url=${env.db.url}
> >     db.default.driver=${env.db.driver}
> >     db.default.user=${env.db.user}
> >     db.default.pass=${env.db.password}`
> >
> > my-play-project/conf/env/devlab/project.properties
> >     
> >     `db.url=myoracleserver.lab.org:1521
> >     db.driver=oracle.thin
> >     db.user=myname
> >     db.password=mypassword`
> >
> > my-play-project/conf/env/devlab2/project.properties
> >     
> >     `db.url=myoracleserver2.lab.org:1521
> >     db.driver=oracle.thin
> >     db.user=myname
> >     db.password=mypassword`

Q. Is there a way to set devlab/project.properties to be part of system resolvable properties?

Comment: Take a look to doc: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionConfiguration

Comment: I use tomcat container and use play2war plugin from declan to get the war which then hot deploys. Therefore, I cannot use start scripts as you would in production mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play's [configuration](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Configuration) uses [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config). There are several ways of combining configuration together on the classpath and at runtime.

- Creating multiple `application.conf` and `application.properties` files and putting them all on the classpath (i.e. in different JARs). The configuration will be combined. See [Standard Behavior](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior).
- Using `include`s to pull in files with different names.
- Using [substitutions](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior) to pull in values from other config files.
- Using substitutions to pull in [environment variables or system properties](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#optional-system-or-env-variable-overrides).